# Nextjs with Material UI and custom global stylesheet

Tags: material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I use Nextjs 9.3 with `export` to generate a static site. Material UI is set up according to this reference implementation (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs).

Additionally to Material UI, I have a global stylesheet `style.css` which is `imported` into `_app.js` according to the documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support).

However after running `export`, `index.html` does not include any of the CSS from `styles.css` only that of Material UI. `styles.css` is only loaded as a normal stylesheet and not inlined. Any way to inject `styles.css` into `index.html` too to avoid FOUC?

EDIT
Relevant parts of the folder structure as requested by @Dekel:

```
├── pages
│   ├── _app.js
│   ├── _document.js
│   ├── index.js
├── public
└── src
    ├── components
    └── styles.css
```

Comment: Can you show the folder structure that you have?

Comment: How are you importing styles.css?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet exactly like this

Answer (score 1):

if what are you looking for is to have your css files concat and minified inside the index.html in this way:

#### Case 0

```html
// index.html
...
<head>
  <style>
    <!-- your css concat + minified here -->
  </style>
</head>
...
```

and not in this way

#### Case 1

```html
// index.html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bundle.min.css"/>
</head>
```

I think you can't achieve this with NextJS out-of-the-box solution "Built-In CSS Support for Global Stylesheets".

Reading the doc from 9.2 release (https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2#built-in-css-support-for-global-stylesheets) it says:

`In production, all CSS files will be automatically concatenated into a single minified .css file. This CSS file will be loaded via a <link> tag and automatically injected into the default HTML markup Next.js generates.`

So, it doesn't seem to me that you can achieve `Case 0` with that solution.

---

I had the same problem of `FOUC` and this is how I managed for my SSR solution with Next:

1. helper function to concat & minify the files I need called `prepareInPageCss.js` which save a js module which returns a string with the bundled css as shown below:

```js
const minify = require('@node-minify/core');
const cleanCSS = require('@node-minify/clean-css');
const fs = require('fs');
const bootstrapOutPutPathName = './static/css/_tempBootstrap.min.js';
const commonOutPutPathName = './static/css/_tempCommon.min.js';
const outputnameCss = './static/css/InPageCssBundle.css';

(async () => {
 try {
   await minify({
     compressor: cleanCSS,
     input: './static/css/bootstrap.min.css',
     output: bootstrapOutPutPathName,
     options: {
       keepSpecialComments: '0'
     }
   });

   await minify({
     compressor: cleanCSS,
     input: './static/css/common.css',
     output: commonOutPutPathName,
     options: {
       keepSpecialComments: '0'
     }
   });

   let bootstrapTempCss = fs.readFileSync(bootstrapOutPutPathName, "utf-8");
   let commonTempCss = fs.readFileSync(commonOutPutPathName, "utf-8");

   fs.writeFileSync(outputnameCss, bootstrapTempCss + commonTempCss);
   fs.writeFileSync(outputname, "const bundledCss=String.raw`" + bootstrapTempCss + commonTempCss + "`; export default bundledCss;");
 } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
 }
})()
```

2. In the file of your project where is the `head` structure I've done in this way:

```js
   import commonCss from '../static/css/InPageCssBundle.js';
   const isDev = ENV === 'development';

   ...
    <title>{title}</title>
    <meta name='description' content={description}/>
    <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
    {isDev ? <>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/common.css"/>
     </> :
     <style>
       {commonCss}
     </style>
   }
   ...
```

Every time I create a new build I run `node path/to/file/prepareInPageCss.js`.

Now, I'm not 100% sure this is the only way (I've implemented this while Next was at 9.0) and I didn't try on static export yet but hope I gave you at least a fallback solution.

Cheers